# What does the ":-" parameter do?

Tags: code-signing, macos

I'm trying to understand the codesign command. Both of the following works fine:

```
codesign -d --entitlements :- /Applications/Numbers.app/
codesign -d --entitlements - /Applications/Numbers.app/
```

I'm wondering what does `:-` and `-` mean here? I couldn't find the relevant information from `codesign --help`.

Does anyone know?

Comment: Where did you get the commands from?

Comment: @nohillside From multi articles, e.g https://www.microsoft.com/security/blog/2022/07/13/uncovering-a-macos-app-sandbox-escape-vulnerability-a-deep-dive-into-cve-2022-26706/

Comment: I don't see the `:-` syntax in there.

Comment: @nohillside I actually found `:-` in the man page for `codesign` command, but it doesn't actually explain what is the difference between `:-` and `-`, so it does exist for macOS command line, but I don't know what it stands for either.